# Find closest record by datetime and state

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a query that will be able to return record from the following tables in specific order.

Descriptions table:

| DescriptionId | AssessmentId | YearId | CreatedAt | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 55 | 2018 | 2022-02-06 15:09:49.500 | 0 |
| 68 | 55 | 2019 | 2022-02-06 15:11:14.167 | 0 |
| 71 | 55 | 2020 | 2022-02-06 15:12:03.780 | 1 |

Threads table:

| ThreadId | AssessmentId | ImpactId | CreatedAt | State |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 60 | 55 | 1 | 2022-02-06 15:09:49.5 | 0 |
| 65 | 55 | 2 | 2022-02-06 15:10:10.97 | 0 |
| 67 | 55 | 3 | 2022-02-06 15:10:18.657 | 0 |
| 69 | 55 | 4 | 2022-02-06 15:11:20.483 | 0 |
| 70 | 55 | 5 | 2022-02-06 15:11:27.263 | 1 |

Idea is to connect 1 Description to 1 Thread depending on `CreatedAt` and `State` column.

The last records in both tables are always already connected by state, so there is no need to check the date.

Past record are required to check by `CreatedAt`.

As far I can tell, it has to go from the newest record to oldest.
So the last record is checked by state, and the next record is checked by date.

The `DescriptionId` record with ID `68` is connected to `ThreadId`
70 because the `CreatedAt` of the thread is older than the `CreatedAt` of Description.

The Description with ID 56 is connected to `ThreadId` 67 is because the thread date is older than the description date and younger than the next date of the new `Description`.

Data and schema is available on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/30878/2)

Result should look like following:

| DescriptionId | CreatedAt(Description) | ThreadId | CreatedAt (Thread) |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 2022-02-06 15:09:49.500 | 67 | 2022-02-06 15:10:18.657 |  |
| 68 | 2022-02-06 15:11:14.167 | 70 | 2022-02-06 15:11:27.263 |  |
| 71 | 2022-02-06 15:12:03.780 | 70 | 2022-02-06 15:11:27.263 | (because of the same state) |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following commented code does what you need:

```
SELECT
    D.DescriptionId,
    [CreatedAt(Description)] = D.CreatedAt,
    T.ThreadId,
    [CreatedAt(Thread)] = T.CreatedAt
FROM 
(
    -- Find next CreatedAt date
    SELECT D.*,
        NextCreatedAt = LEAD(D.CreatedAt, 1, D.CreatedAt) OVER (
        PARTITION BY D.AssessmentId 
        ORDER BY D.CreatedAt)
    FROM dbo.Descriptions AS D
) AS D
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- State match
    SELECT TOP (1) T.* 
    FROM dbo.Threads AS T
    WHERE T.AssessmentId = D.AssessmentId
    AND D.[State] = 1 
    AND T.[State] = 1

    -- Or
    UNION ALL 

    -- No State match
    SELECT TOP (1) T.* 
    FROM dbo.Threads AS T
    WHERE T.AssessmentId = D.AssessmentId
    AND D.[State] = 0
    AND T.CreatedAt > D.CreatedAt
    AND T.CreatedAt < D.NextCreatedAt
    ORDER BY T.CreatedAt DESC
) AS T;
```

| DescriptionId | CreatedAt(Description) | ThreadId | CreatedAt(Thread) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | 2022-02-06 15:09:49.500 | 67 | 2022-02-06 15:10:18.657 |
| 68 | 2022-02-06 15:11:14.167 | 70 | 2022-02-06 15:11:27.263 |
| 71 | 2022-02-06 15:12:03.780 | 70 | 2022-02-06 15:11:27.263 |

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a6faabd4778443ae8593176714dfb102)